# Why is this not executed in the forEach method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, discord, discord.js

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
    const joinRoles = db.getRoles(member.guildId);

    joinRoles.data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.role + "meee1")
    });

    console.log("meee2")
})
```

So, to the question, why is this not executed in the forEach method?

Once a user joins the guild nothing is done except meee2 is shown, meee1 is not shown for whatever reason. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks fine. Are you sure that joinRoles.data is not empty?

Comment: if I do it as a command, make it from console.log() to message.channel.send() and then run it, it will show what in the forEach :C

Comment: @GavinHaynes nono, is not empty, if i do it as command, then works, but guildMemberAdd not working :c if it were empty, it would still have to display meee1 in my case, wouldn't it? i.e. only meee1, but nothing is output, only skipped somehow.

Comment: Try adding console.log(joinRoles) to see what is inside .data

Comment: Can you show your `getRoles` method.

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/zosicezesi.kotlin 
I hope this is ok

Comment: Please do `console.log(joinRoles.data)` outside the forEach like @PhilippPanik said. I can only see this happening if its empty. And no, if it is empty, it wouldn't log anything.

Comment: well, it is empty. but the database, it's filled with strings. When I run this as command it shows me what is in it, when I try it with guildMemberAdd it is supposed to be empty :(

Comment: GUYS GUYS, problem solved. The database was really empty, weilll it didn't find member.guildId, so no guildId found, I had to make it member.guild.id, now everything works. THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR HELP

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're dealing with an empty array (assuming you don't get any errors in the console) and considering that almost all DB's have some sort of latency and even your function is marked as `async` I'd assume that you might have to use `await` in front of `db.getRoles()` call. I also assume that `getRoles` is returning a promise and you could try and debug to see what is happening while you're adding a new guild member.